# Bluemix node.js app sends 502 Bad Gateway responses during the push of a new app

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I am pushing a node.js app to IBM Bluemix by using the blue-to-green pattern.

Basically my Jenkins job is doing the following steps:

- **upload the new app:** cf push my-app-tmp -f cf/manifest-my-app.yml -n my-app-tmp
- **add the app to the loadbalancer**: cf map-route my-app-tmp mybluemix.net -n my-app
- **delete the old app**:
  cf delete my-app -f
- **rename the new app to the old name**: cf rename my-app-tmp my-app
- **remove the old route**:
  cf unmap-route my-app mybluemix.net -n my-app-tmp

During this process my app is sometimes returning 502 Bad Gateway. It seems to be a problem with the loadbalancer for me, any ideas?

Comment: Can you share some of your logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the pattern again:
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

You still have a map to the running **old** app when you delete it. The router may send requests to it until it get's it that the old app is destroyed. Delete allows a parameter to remove the mapping but just to make sure: un-map the old app and then delete it. You can even pause a little while before deleting it to allow it to process whatever it was doing.

But remember: In clouds expect to fail! Retry if it makes sense. So even the 502 shouldn't have an effect on something using your app because it recovers quickly.

HP

Comment: Okay, I have added the following before the deletion step, now it works:

unmap the old app: cf unmap-route my-app mybluemix.net -n my-app
Thank you for your help.